# Updating SSL Certs with PKCS12 or PEM via Bash Script

Tags: debian, ssl, cron, letsencrypt

I currently have my pi-hole setup to request an SSL cert from ZeroSSL using Acme.sh, this works quite well.

I then have to cat the two cert and key files into one, and then relaunch the lighttpd server from cli.

I have the crontab -l listed below:

```
47 3 * * * "/root/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/root/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
59 3 * * 6 /bin/bash cat pi-hole01.na.com.key pi-hole01.na.com.cer > pi-hole01.na.com.pem
15 4 * * 6 systemctl restart lighttpd
```

What is a more reliable way to refresh the pem, and restart the service?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: The fact you are seeking opinions is the problem.  You should have done the leg work on the research on the process to automatically renew your self-signed TLS certificate before asking this question. Even the title of the question is problematic, since the definition of "a better method", is highly subjective. For instance, my "better" method is to use an entirely separate TLS CA Root Authority (Let's Encrypt) that already has the automatic renewal process documented.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by updated if not renewed? TLS certificates are typically valid and static for at least 90-365 days. I am an engineer. It’s difficult to shutdown the pedantic side of my brain.

Comment: @Ramhound I deleted my comments, and added an answer that is suitable, any suggestions to the answer that may clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and discussion, and working on a different but similar issue, I have come across an explanation that required some tweaking to fix the issues I was experiencing.

My solution to this was simple, find a script that read a hash of the cert, and then update it if the test passed a 1 rather than a 0.

*More Clarifications* The SSL auth is being done through Cloudflare using these instructions originally for Unifi. These can be used until the actual renewal.
https://www.markuszehnle.com/2018/07/02/secure-ubiquiti-unifi-controller-cloudkey-with-an-lets-encrypt-certificate/

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
HOST="sub.root.tld"
ACMEHOME=/root/.acme.sh
CERTDIR=${ACMEHOME}/${HOST}
CERTPASS="somepasswordifyouneedpkcs12" #For this use case I needed PKCS12
DESTDIR="/etc/sslcerts" #The location where your cert should reside after being encrypted.
PKFXFILE="plex-certificate.pkfx" #The Name of the File as a packed cert

#Below is the logic as run under debian, but I am sure regular distro's should read it similar.

TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
md5sum ${CERTDIR}/${HOST}.cer > ${TMPFILE}
${ACMEHOME}/acme.sh --cron --home ${ACMEHOME}
md5sum -c ${TMPFILE}
if [ $? -eq 0 ] #compares the output of md5sum to the hash, and passes 1 or 0.
then
  # nothing has changed
  rm -f ${TMPFILE}
  exit 0
else
  # something changed! Quick update the cert!
  openssl pkcs12 -export -out ${DESTDIR}/${PKFXFILE} -inkey ${CERTDIR}/${HOST}.key -in ${CERTDIR}/${HOST}.cer -certfile ${CERTDIR}/fullchain.cer -passout pass:${CERTPASS}
  chmod 644 ${DESTDIR}/${PKFXFILE}
  chown plex:plex ${DESTDIR}/${PKFXFILE}
  rm -f ${TMPFILE}
fi

#Uncomment to restart Plex as needed.
#systemctl restart plexmediaserver
```

Vincent Danen is the original author of the BSD script that I copied.
https://annvix.com/blog/using-letsencrypt-with-plex

As a deeper dive with continued explanations this script can be modified to add pem support looking like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST="sub.root.tld"
ACMEHOME=/root/.acme.sh
CERTDIR=${ACMEHOME}/${HOST}
#DESTDIR="/etc/sslcerts" #The location where your cert should reside after being encrypted if you so choose.
MRGFILE="merged-certificate.pem" #Name of your file including the extension: pem

#Below is the logic as run under debian, but I am sure regular distro's should read it similar.

TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
md5sum ${CERTDIR}/${HOST}.cer > ${TMPFILE}
${ACMEHOME}/acme.sh --cron --home ${ACMEHOME}
md5sum -c ${TMPFILE}
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  #compares the output of md5sum to the hash, and passes 1 or 0.
  # nothing has changed
  rm -f ${TMPFILE}
  exit 0
else
  # something changed! Quick update the cert!
  cat ${CERTDIR}/${HOST}.cer ${CERTDIR}/${HOST}.key > ${CERTDIR}/${MRGFILE}
  chmod 644 ${CERTDIR}/${MRGFILE}
  rm -f ${TMPFILE}
  # Uncomment to restart desired service as needed.
  systemctl restart lighttpd #Service name is at the end.
fi
```

In your root crontab this is what it should be called by.

```
47 3 * * * "/root/"namedscripthere.sh > /dev/null
```